# JavaScript - Determine how a user arrived at html page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a web application and for one of my pages, I need to determine how a user arrived at the page (i.e. by redirect or by directly typing in the URL).

Is this possible with vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: You should have a backend server , node.js is good choice for you (cause you know how to code on Javascript) if you keep determine every user every day. redis-bitset it good friend for you !

Answer (score 0):

[document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer).

You can also read [Referer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) header on your backend server, because browser automatically includes it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `document.referrer`

If somone types url in address bar it should return an empty string, otherwise if a link was clicked it should return prior page url

Comment: I tried this, but it always returns an empty string, regardless of how I access the page. Am I using this correctly? `if(document.referrer === '') {
          alert('URL');
        } else {
          alert('REDIRECT');
        }`